# Delete button in CGrid view in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I tried to create a Delete button in CButtonColumn,The problem is when I triggered the delete,It shows me an error **Your request is invalid.**.Can anyone tell me why this is happening....
**My controller**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

**And my view**

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'replay-comment-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    // 'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        //'id',
        //'comment_id',
        'admin_replay',
        array(
                'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'180px'),
                'template' => '{view}&nbsp;{update}&nbsp;{delete}',
                'buttons' => array(
                        'view'=>array(
                            'imageUrl' =>false,
                            'label' => 'View', 
                            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("replayComment/view/$data->id")',
                            'options' => array('title'=>'view','class'=>'btn btn-success btn-xs'),
                        ),
                        'update'=>array(
                            'imageUrl' =>false,
                            'label' => '',
                            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("replayComment/update/$data->id")',
                            'options' => array('title'=>'update','class'=>'btn btn-info btn-xs fa fa-pencil-square-o'),
                                ),    
                        'delete'=>array(
                            'imageUrl' =>false,
                            'label' => 'delete', 
                            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("replayComment/delete/$data->id")',
                            'options' => array('title'=>'delete','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-xs'),
                        ),                                  
                )
            ),
    ),
    'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover',
        'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination', 
        'pager'=>array( 'header' => '','lastPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>','firstPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>','prevPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>','nextPageLabel'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>','header' => '','cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/pager.css','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pagination'),'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active'),
)); ?>
```

Comment: Have you even watched the `Network` in `Developer Console` of your browser? What received and what sent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine except for the url attribute, can you try:

```
    'delete'=>array(
               'imageUrl' =>false,
               'label'   => 'delete', 
               'url'     =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("replayComment/delete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
               'options' => array('title'=>'delete','class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-xs'),
         ),
```

the id parameter value will be passed in an array. 
[Yii create url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

Also you shouldn't add `&nbsp;` in 
`'template' => '{view}&nbsp;{update}&nbsp;{delete}',` use the button classes instead.

Comment: thank you for the answer..but it still shows the same error

Comment: @MohammedIqbal can you show me what kind of url you are getting when you click on the delete button ?

Answer (score 0):

Did u properly setup your application CUrlManager  to understand how to parse such urls ? test the controller and action fire correctly  by directly type the url at the address bar rather try it from grid delete button.

```
ocalhost/sanmrc/replayComment/delete/2
```

something like

```
array(
    'replayComment/delete/<id:\d+>'=>'replayComment/delete',
)
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls